# Trying to validate YYYY/MM/dd

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are a lot of regex threads out there but I couldn't find anywhere.

I have a regex that work well with DD/MM/YYYY format.
Here it is:

```
^((0?[13578]|1[02])[\/.]31[\/.][1-9][0-9]{3})|(([01,1]|0[3-9]|1[1-2])[\/.](29|30)[\/.][1-9][0-9]{3})|((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/.](0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\/.][1-9][0-9]{3})|([02,2][\/.]29[\/.](([1-9][0-9](04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|([2468][0]{3})))$
```

**Example:** 29/2/2014,31/4/2014...

But when i was trying to validate with YYYY/MM/DD format, i had found this:

```
^(((19|20)([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48])|2000)[\/.]02[\/.]29|((19|20)[0-9]{2}[\/.](0?[469]|11)[\/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[\/.](0?[13578]|1[02])[\/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(19|20)[0-9]{2}[\/.]02[\/.](0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])))$
```

This pattern just only works with YYYY from: 19xx -> 20xxx.

When i changed it, I expect it can work well with YYYY from: 1xxx ->9xxx. But it did not do well.

I'm new in regex, and it's hard to escape it.

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Do you have to use regular expressions? Splitting on `/`, parsing each part as an integer and making the appropriate comparisons would probably be much easier.

Answer (score 4):

## **TL;DR Minitech's comments and TheQ's comments are correct -- this is not a great task for regular expressions. A non-regex solution is given below. Just for kicks, so is a monstrous regex.**

**Edit:** I decided to spend a few minutes at lunch cleaning this up and adding the "right" way to do this (no regex) as well as a jsFiddle.

---

## The Real Answer

The right way to do this for readability, maintainability, and sanity is to avoid using regex here. Writing a regex to do this is extremely difficult and the result is extremely hard to read.

Instead, just parse the date into its component parts, then validate them like so:

```
/**
 * Check whether a given year is a leap year
 * @param integer y The integer
 * @return boolean True for yes, false for no
 */
function isLeapYear(y) {
    return (0 == y % 4 && (0 == y % 400 || 0 != y % 100));
}

/**
 * Validate a date in YYYY/MM/DD format (allows YYYY/M/D and periods instead of slashes) without regex.
 * @param string str The date to test.
 * @return boolean True for valid, false for invalid.
 */
function validateDateWithoutRegex(str) {
    // check the format first
    if(!/^\d{4}[\/.]\d{1,2}[\/.]\d{1,2}$/.test(str)) {
        return false;
    }
    var parts = str.split(/\D/) // split on non-digits
        .map(function(val) { return parseInt(val); }); // convert strings to ints
    if(parts[0] < 1000 || parts[0] > 2999) { // invalid year
        return false;
    }
    if(parts[1] > 12 || parts[1] === 0) { // invalid month
        return false;
    }
    if(parts[2] > 31 || parts[2] === 0) { // invalid day
        return false;
    }
    switch(parts[1]) {
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            if(parts[2] > 30) { // invalid day
                return false;
            }
            break;
        case 2: // February...
            return (parts[2] < 29 || parts[2] == 29 && isLeapYear(parts[0]));
            break;
    }
    return true;       
}

// Usage: validateDateWithoutRegex('2014/07/28'); // returns true
```

---

## The Utterly Insane Regex Answer

But, just because I felt like doing some regex tonight... you *could* use this monster:

```
/^(?=(?!\d+\D0?2\D29)|(?:\d{2}(?:04|08|[13579][26]|[2468][048])|1[26]00|2000)\D0?2\D29$)([12]\d{3})[\/.]((?:0?[13578]|10|12)[\/.](?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1])|(?:0?[469]|11)[\/.](?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|0?2[\/.](?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-9]))$/
```

This even validates leap years.

[**Here's an interactive jsFiddle that also runs 50+ unit tests**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/uK8Kn/8/) to validate that this method works the same way as the non-regex method.

And [**here's a Regex101 DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/tD8lI5/5)

Possibly helpful explanation, courtesy of Debuggex:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6kP7yhblKaZ7rytv)

Example matches:

- 2014/12/31
- 1937/4/17
- 1066/1/4
- 1066/2/28
- 2014/1/1
- 2012/02/29
- 2000/02/29 (multiples of 400 are leap years)
- 1600/02/29 (multiples of 400 are leap years)
- 2015/01/01

Example non-matches:

- 1900/02/29 (multiples of 100 that are not multiples of 400 are not leap years)
- 2012/02/30
- 2012/00/01
- 2012/00/00
- 2012/04/31
- 2012/17/01
- 2012/02/00
- 1066/1/4444
- 1066/2/29
- 1065/2/29
- 2014/14/1
- 2014/02/29

It's late, so helpful suggestions would be appreciated.

## A Note on Historical Problems with Both Approaches

The Gregorian calendar is tied up in the history of the Protestant Reformation, among other things. It was highly controversial when it was created, and has not been adopted universally. The places that have adopted it did so at different times and in different ways. The result: which dates are valid in the Gregorian calendar depends on where you are. [See, e.g., Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar).

Essentially, the Gregorian calendar came into existence in 1582. Its adoption has varied by country since then. For example, the calendar essentially defined out of existence October 5 through 14 in 1582. Many countries likewise skipped days to shift the old (Julian) calendar dates to match the Gregorian calendar, but they didn't all skip the same days (or even the same number of days); which days they skipped depended on the country and when it adopted the calendar.

So, to the extent you want to be able to validate dates prior to 1582 (or even 1923 in some places), keep all of this in mind. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Ed Cottrell and every answer, it's such a helpfull suggestions.

Comment: How do we force user to always enter 2 numbers in month or in date? I meant I expect my format to be always YYYY/MM/DD (and NOT YYYY/M/D or NOT YYYY/M/DD or NOT YYYY/MM/D)

Comment: @user613114 that’s really a new question and should be asked as a new question, not as a comment. That said, there’s a pretty easy tweak to the format-checking step in my answer that would allow you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Only using regex to validate dates is a bad idea, because of leap years. I would use the pattern `^\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}$` in javascript, and do a more complete validation on the server side. This pattern is also much more easy to understand and make modifications to.

Comment: +1 for having the right answer. I'm just being ridiculous with mine. :)